# how to remark date between dates?

Tags: php

I have table for tasks list.

how can I create condition for dates?

I want to give red color for tasks that their targerDate are in 2 days or less.

```
    $mainQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tasks `");
    while($mainIndex = mysql_fetch_array($mainQuery)) 
{
if ($mainIndex['tagertDate'] <= ???)
}
```

sql table:

```
id  int(10) 
title   varchar(250)    utf8_general_ci
text    text    utf8_general_ci
catID   tinyint(3)  
createUserID    int(4)  
createDate  date    
targetDate  date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Executing below query. It will return date which are less that or equal to next 2 day.

```
 SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE targetDate <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 day);
```

Comment: why do you give me SELECT query?